# Auto click bullets on slider to make slider autoplay for all slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a custom slider which can rotate each image when I click the bullets. I need to make it autoplay, so I want if the page is ready, it's trigger click on the 1st bullet, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc and back to 1st bullet again...
but it just works for 1st and 2nd slides only.

The bullets using attr `data-container` for each slide `id`:

```
<nav class="thumb-nav">
        <a data-container="container-1" class="thumb-nav__item" href="#"><span>1</span></a>
        <a data-container="container-2" class="thumb-nav__item" href="#"><span>2</span></a>
                    <a data-container="container-3" class="thumb-nav__item" href="#"><span>3</span></a>
        <a data-container="container-4" class="thumb-nav__item" href="#"><span>4</span></a>
    </nav>
```

and these are the slide contents:

```
<div id="container-1" class="container theme-1">
        <header class="intro">
            <img class="intro__image" src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlidingHeaderLayout/img/header01.jpg" alt="Lava"/>
            <!-- /intro__content -->
        </header><!-- /intro -->
    </div><!-- /container -->
    <div id="container-2" class="container theme-2">
        <header class="intro">
            <img class="intro__image" src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlidingHeaderLayout/img/header02.jpg" alt="Road"/>
            <!-- /intro__content -->
        </header><!-- /intro -->

    </div>
 <div id="container-3" class="container theme-3">
        <header class="intro">
              <img class="intro__image" src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlidingHeaderLayout/img/header03.jpg"     alt="Lava"/>
         </header>
 </div>
 <div id="container-4" class="container theme-4">
        <header class="intro">
            <img class="intro__image" src="http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlidingHeaderLayout/img/header02.jpg" alt="Lava"/>
      </header>
   </div>
```

and here's my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vdp1708/9fupL7hc/3/)

Any help is going to be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setInterval` is not supposed to be inside the forEach loop.

```
var pageIndex = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    pageIndex ++;
    if(pageIndex >= pageTriggers.length) pageIndex = 0;
    navigate( pageTriggers[pageIndex] );
}, 5000);
```

Refer [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fupL7hc/4/)

Hope this helps. Let me know if your question is not answered.

**Edit:**

```
if(pageIndex >= pageTriggers.length)
```

**Note:**
I am creating a new `pageIndex` here, you might consider using your already defined global variable `current`.

Comment: thankyou @Vinod Kumar , but when it state on the last slide, it can't back to 1st slide again . any suggestion?

Comment: Hi @vanio178, the edit should help with that. Replace the condition, with the edited one. I will update my answer...

Comment: The problem with this is that it ignores what the current slide is and creates its own index. @vanio178's code has an index already: `current`. If you click on the slide that is coming next it will be stuck there for 10 seconds. If you click to skip a slide it will move back to the one skipped. Also @VinodKumar, note the indentation error on line 2.

Comment: @jcuenod, yes your point is very valid. I will make a note on that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**First:** You need to move your `setInterval` block outside of your outside of `pageTriggers.forEach` block. As you have it, it is creating a timer for each of the slides but then the first one is overriding the others (which is why it's only bouncing between your first two slides).

**Second:** Outside of the `forEach` you can't pass `this` to your `navigate` function. So you're going to need some other way of figuring out which slide to go to. That new slide is represented below by `newIndex`.

**Solution:**

```
setInterval(function () {
    var newIndex = current + 1 >= pageTriggers.length ? 0 : current + 1
    navigate(pageTriggers[newIndex]);
}, 5000);
```

See the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57cvLy2c/1/)**.

Nice job though, I like it.